# Ordered field proof that squared terms are zero or positive

Tags: real-analysis

I have decided to set up a bounty for one outstanding solution to this problem. The winner with the most clear, confident, solution manual-esque response will be awarded 50 of my participation points. The answer must be clear and unambiguous. You should attempt to solve the problem as if this were a midterm/final exam environment. It must show me clearly that either my attempt was completely off or on the right track. Good luck!

I am completely lost on how to answer this question. I have a feeling this is somewhat of an awkward proof. If I am missing something all hints will help!

Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $a_1 \in F,a_2 \in F,...,a_n \in F$,where $F$ is an ordered field

then $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k^2 \geq 0$$

I know I have to attempt this to receive a competent answer, so here it goes:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{1} a_1^2 \geq0$$

since $|a_1|^2 \geq 0$

This looks like an induction problem but I want to argue that anything in an ordered field squared is positive or $0$.

Assume $$\sum_{k=1}^{n_0} a_k^2 \geq 0$$

Therefore

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n_0} a_{k}^2 +a_{n_0+1}^2 \geq 0$$

Since $|a_1|^2+\ldots+|a_{n_0}|^2+|a_{n_0+1}|^2 \geq 0$

So by induction

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k^2 \geq 0$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: I think you have a good idea to focus on whether one square term is nonnegative.  Setting aside the trivial case $a^2=0$ one can assume either $a$ or $-a$ is positive, and either way we get $a^2$ is positive.  So the base case is easy if you choose to think of it that way.

Comment: @hardmath does this mean I should have three cases for both the inductive and base steps. One for all terms equaling zero, one for all positive terms and one for all negative terms?

Comment: Once the single square term is shown to be nonnegative,  you don't need trichotomy for the proof that a finite sum of nonnegative of terms is nonnegative.   I'll try and find a previous Question that does this argument, but the base case is really a sum of two nonnegative terms.

Comment: @hardmath thanks. Also are the absolute values unnecessary? I think that the answer to this problem should lie in the theorem that if $a \in F$ and $a \neq 0$ then $a^2>0$ I'm just not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 4):

**Definition of ordered filed**

A field $(F, +, \cdot)$ together with a (strict) total order $<$ on $F$ is an ordered field if the order satisfies the following properties for all $a, b$ and $c$ in $F$:

- if $a < b$ then $a + c < b + c$, and
- if $0 < a$ and $0 < b$ then $0 < a\cdot b$.

  ---

**Lemma**:  $\forall a \in F$, $a^2 \ge 0$.

**Proof**:

- If $a=0$, then $a^2 = 0 \cdot (1-1)=0\cdot 1 - 0 \cdot 1 = 0-0=0$ where I have used definition of additive inverse and distributive law.
- If $a>0$, then $a^2=a\cdot a>0$ by definition of ordered field.
- If $a<0$, adding $-a$ to both sides, we have $0<-a$. Also $1+(-1)=0$ by squaring, $$(1+(-1))\cdot (1+(-1)) = 0$$ which can be expanded to $$1+(-1)+(-1)+(-1)^2=0$$
  $$-1+(-1)^2=0$$

That is $$(-1)^2=1.$$

Hence $$a^2=1\cdot a^2 = (-1)^2 \cdot a^2 = (-a)^2>0$$

That is $$\forall a \in F, a^2 \ge 0. \square$$

---

Claim: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \ge 0.$

Base case: For $n=1$, this has been shown by the lemma.

Suppose we have $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i^2 \ge 0$

we want to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_i^2 \ge 0$.

This is true because

\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_i^2  &= \left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i^2\right) + a_{k+1}^2
\ge 0\end{align}

because $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i^2\right) \ge 0$ and $a_{k+1}^2 \ge 0$.

Hence, by mathematical induction, $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \ge 0.$$

Answer (score 3):

The absolute value is a way of abbreviating the argument from trichotomy.   Likely the purpose of the exercise is to practice making an argument from [the definition (axioms) of an ordered field](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field).

You should review how the definition was presented in your study materials.  The historical development was originally by imposing a binary relation $\le$ as a *total order* on field elements so that the sum of two positive elements is positive and the product of two positive elements is positive.  (Here "positive" means being greater than and *not* equal to zero.)

An alternative approach is to focus on a subset of the field elements that are greater than or equal to zero, ascribing to that subset properties that amount to creating a total order (trichotomy) and closure under taking sums and products.

The crux of the proof you've identified is:

**Lemma** For any element $a\in F$ an ordered field, $0\le a^2$.

The way I sketched in my original comment is to use trichotomy to argue one of three cases must hold.  If $a=0$ then $a^2=0$ and we are done.  If $a\gt 0$, then $a^2$ is positive (by closure under taking products of two positive elements).  Finally the only other possibility is that $a\lt 0$, then $-a \gt 0$, and we arrive at the same conclusion because $a^2 = (-a)^2 \gt 0$.